# calculate and return the difference between the second largest number and the second smallest number

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists, numpy-slicing

Given a Python list, calculate and return the difference between the second largest number and the second smallest number. Assume that the list contains two or more elements.
Function Specifications:
The second largest / smallest must be different to the largest / smallest number in a list. That is:

```
difference([10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1]) == 8 - 2 == 6
```

Should take a list as input.

```
def difference(list1):

    # Your code here

    return*
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have tried this : # def difference(list1):
  return list1[::-1]

difference = difference([10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1])

print(difference) #  it seem to be able to sort the list but i cant get it to subtract the largest number and the second largest, as i am expected to sort and return the difference between the last two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple, but not most efficient way. you can achieve that by two step:

1. convert `list` to `set`, to remove the duplicate number.
2. use `heap` to find `nlargest` and `nsmallest` in `set`

```
def difference(list1):
    set1 = set(list1)
    return heapq.nlargest(2, set1)[1] - heapq.nsmallest(2, set1)[1]
```

---

Here is a one pass way, more efficient way, use 4 variables:

```
def difference(list1):
    max1, max2, min1, min2 = float('-inf'), float('-inf'), float('inf'), float('inf')
    for x in list1:
        if x > max1:
            max1, max2 = x, max1
        elif x >= max2 and x != max1:
            max2 = x

        if x < min1:
            min1, min2 = x, min1
        elif x <= min2 and x != min1:
            min2 = x

    return max2 - min2
```

test and output:

```
print(difference([10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1]))
# 6
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

First we onstruct a set out of given list to remove duplicated values, and then sort them to easly find second highest and smallest values.

```
def difference(list1):
    list1 = sorted(set(list1))
    print(list1) # --> [1, 2, 5, 8, 10]

    if list1[1] != list1[-2]:
        return list1[-2] - list1[1]

print(difference([10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1]) == 8 - 2 == 6) # --> True
```